# Ski jump result combinations

Tags: probability, combinatorics, factorial

**Problem**

> In ski jumping, there are 50 jumpers competing in the first round. The 30 best jumpers move on to the second round.
>
> a) How many different combinations of 30 jumpers can get to the second round in a competition?
>
> b) How many different result lists can we get in a competition with jumpers that have jumped in two rounds?

**My thoughts**

For a), I just figure it's ${50 \choose 30}$ to get the number of different combinations.

For b), I'm thinking it's ${50 \choose 30}$ again, but multiplied by how many ways you can place thirty jumpers on a list. Meaning, I think it's ${50 \choose 30}\cdot 30!$. This feels ridiculously large though, as it gets to be in the order of magnitude of $10^{46}$.

Does this seem right, or am I missing something?

Comment: I think only the jumpers who have made it to the second round are to be considered, so there can be $30!$ lists

Comment: @trueblueanil That's a good point.